# How to use Ruby on Rails Associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Description:** I am following the toy_app tutorial on: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app

I am having issues with an Exercise question under section 2.3.3

**Question:** Edit the user show page to display the content of the user’s first micropost. (Use your technical sophistication (Box 1.1) to guess the syntax based on the other content in the file.) Confirm by visiting /users/1 that it worked.

Within my *app/views/users/show.html.erb* file. I tried using my **@micropost.content** object to display any content associated with the user.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @user.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Email:</strong>
  <%= @user.email %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Content:</strong>
  <%= (<%= @micropost.content %>) %>
</p>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

**Result**

> NoMethodError in Users#show
>
> undefined method 'content' for nil:NilClass

**Conclusion**

Do I need to generate a **form_for** for my posts for my *app/view/user* file? Or, because I'm setting my **:content** object within a private 'micropost_params' method in my microposts_controller.rb, that it will not allow object data transfer between controllers?

I tested within console the following lines of code to make sure association is working:

```
first_user = User.first
first_user.microposts
micropost = first_user.microposts.first
micropost.user
```

I feel that I need to define a method within my User controller file that gives access to my :content object within my MicroPosts Class.

Comment: Do you set `@micropost` variable in your controller's `show` method?

Comment: It should be `@user.micropost.content`, or export `@micropost = User.first.microposts` in your controller, and handle the array in the view.

Comment: @joaumg: actually, neither will work. It should be something else :)

Comment: @Ryan Anderson, could you show us your models & controller (the show method ?)

Comment: Thanks guys, I (embarrassingly) had nothing within my 'show' method. I was trying to put that code all of you gave me within my view....and nothing was defined within my controller's show method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `show` action should look something like the following.

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @micropost = @user.microposts.first
end
```

Now, in the view, you can access the micropost's content using `@micropost.content`. What if the user has no microposts associated with him(hasn't written a micropost)? In that case, `@user.microposts.first` will be `nil`. If you're not sure what I mean, try playing with it in the rails console.

```
<% if @micropost %>
  <%= @micropost.content %>
<% else %>
  <p> User has no microposts </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, that makes a lot of sense. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks Arun! Appreciate the knowledge.

Comment: @RyanAnderson You're welcome. Glad I was able to help.